# ServiceStack.ORMLite "resolving" Foreign Keys

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Is there a way to do something like a Join without needing to create a new holding object for the resulting values? For instance, if I have the following:

```
public class Patient
{
   [Alias("PatientId")]
   [Autoincrement]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   [ForeignKey(typeof(Gender))]
   public int GenderId { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Gender
{
   [Alias("GenderId")]
   [Autoincrement]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string GenderName { get; set; }
}
```

I want to store several attributes like Gender, Race, etc in separate tables to provide filters in forms on the front-end of a web application, and also to have a normalized database. I have seen the light with ORMLite in the area of blobbing certain data fields like Addresses that won't really be used anywhere else, but I think I want to stick with standard database structures for this type of information.

That said, I know I can do a Join to get the GenderName like this:

```
public class PatientJoined
{
    [BelongTo(typeof(Patient))]
    public int PatientId { get; set; }
    [BelongTo(typeof(Patient))]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [BelongTo(typeof(Gender))]
    public string GenderName { get; set; }
}

public class PatientService : Service
{
    //Database connection code, resulting in dbConn as IDbConnection object

    public object Get(PatientRequest request)
    {
        var jn = new JoinSqlBuilder<PatientJoined, Patient>();
        jn = jn.Join<Patient, Gender>(x => x.GenderId, x => x.GenderName)
        .Where<Patient>(x => x.Name = request.Name);

        var jnSQL = jn.ToSql();
        var result = dbConn.Select<PatientJoin>(jnSQL);

        return result;
    }
}
```

This works well, except that I need an almost duplicate POCO object with a ton of "[BelongTo]" decorators just to resolve some Foreign Key values. As these objects get larger, this gets to be very cumbersome, no?

I was thinking there might be something kind of like the "LoadReferences" method that could automate Joins where ForeignKey's exist, and then give you access to all of the related tables' fields.

Maybe there would be a way to add extra fields in the original POCO with [Ignore] so they don't end up in the db. Something like:

```
public class Patient
{
   [Alias("PatientId")]
   [Autoincrement]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   [ForeignKey(typeof(Gender))]
   public int GenderId { get; set; }
   [Ignore]
   public string GenderName { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then, if we could resolve and access the ForeignKey references, we could assign "Gender.GenderName" to Patient.GenderName.

I have a feeling I'm searching in the dark on this one, but I'm asking anyway....Thanks!